# Prior for Bayesian multiple logistic regression

Tags: logistic, bayesian, multiple-regression, prior

I was wondering how I could incorporate a prior to form a posterior distribution for multiple logistic regression.

More specifically, I am working with basketball data, where the response variable is binary (whether a player made the shot or not) and the explanatory variables are the distance from the basket and the defensive ratings of the opposing 5 players. I am able to generate multiple seasons worth of these shot logs for each player from the past, and wanted to know how I could take previous seasons of data into account when I also have a current season's worth of data.

Comment: In what sense is this* multivariate*? Do you have multiple response variables?

Comment: Is that what multivariate means? Sorry I meant to say that there are multiple explanatory variables, but the response variable is either 0 or 1

Answer (score 3):

[This article](http://www.medicine.mcgill.ca/epidemiology/joseph/courses/EPIB-621/bayeslogit.pdf) discusses Bayesian logistic regression nicely. Basically, you have the flexibility to parametrize estimation however you see fit, but using a model which is linear on the log odds scale makes sense for many reasons. Furthermore, using a normal prior for log odds ratios should give you very approximately normal posteriors.

To do the sequential analysis, estimate the "prior" for *this season* by doing a first-pass Bayesian logistic regression for *past seasons* using a non-informative normal prior for *that* model.

Comment: Thanks for the response Adam. But what if my covariates are continuous and not discrete?

Comment: @kleiza don't put a prior on your covariates. We generally think of them as "fixed" or given in regression modeling.